# OpenText in Current Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

The [`Workbooks.OpenText` method (Excel) documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext) says:

> *expression*.**OpenText** (*FileName, Origin, StartRow, DataType, TextQualifier, ConsecutiveDelimiter, Tab, Semicolon, Comma, Space, Other, OtherChar, FieldInfo, TextVisualLayout, DecimalSeparator, ThousandsSeparator, TrailingMinusNumbers, Local*)

> *expression* A variable that represents a **Workbooks** object.

In my project I use

```
fPath = "C:\CSV Files\" & FName
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fPath, Local:=True
```

This creates an additional workbook. I want the code to create a new spreadsheet in the existing workbook. I have tried this code

```
fPath = "C:\CSV Files\" & FName
ActiveWorkbook.OpenText Filename:=fPath, Local:=True
```

This pops a Runtime error 438. [This topic](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-365-excel-visual-basic-run-time-error-438/e53dcc83-8878-4c9f-ad8e-5d82807355b8) says:

> When you are trying to use a method/property that does not belong to the object. For instance, if you have a Workbook object and try to access the Range property, it will give you the 438 error since the Range property belongs to the Sheets object.

I am actually using Excel 2020, but I have no idea what is causing the error.

Can anyone put me right, please?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Are you trying to open a txt file?

Answer (score 1):

When you open a text file it'll be opened as a new workbook, you can't immediately add it to an existing workbook.

Try something like this:

```
set OriginalWB = ActiveWorkbook
fPath = "C:\CSV Files\" & FName
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fPath, Local:=True
set newWB = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveSheet.Copy after:= OriginalWB.worksheets(1)
newWB.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

To open a text file into the same workbook, you can use the `AddQueryTables` method to **Import** the file, or you can use PowerQuery

This is some code that was generated by the macro recorder

```
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\tester.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "tester"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```